# Interacting with Google Sheets API using PowerShell

Tags: google-sheets, google-api, google-workspace

I have an Azure Automation runbook that is kicked off when certain violations/incidents occur on my infrastructure. I would like to be able to create a google spreadsheet and store data in the spreadsheet for additional troubleshooting logs. Since I am using Azure Automation, my preference is to do this in Powershell, if possible. Python can be used, but it is not ideal.

Is there a reasonably efficient way to interact with Google Workspace APIs (sheets api, in this case) using Powershell? Is it worth the hassle, or should I just bite the bullet and use Python?

---

Bonus: I was curious, so I looked up the same question in ChatGPT, and this is what it came up with.

```
# Install the Google API client library for PowerShell
Install-Package Google.Apis -ProviderName NuGet

# Import the necessary Google API libraries
Import-Module Google.Apis.Sheets.v4

# Set up the Google API credentials
$credentialsFilePath = "C:\path\to\credentials.json"
$clientSecretsFilePath = "C:\path\to\client_secret.json"
$credential = Get-GoogleOAuth2Credential -ClientSecretsFilePath $clientSecretsFilePath -CredentialsFilePath $credentialsFilePath -Scopes "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"

# Set up the Google Sheets API service
$service = New-GoogleSheetsService -Credential $credential

# Define the new spreadsheet's properties
$spreadsheet = New-Object Google.Apis.Sheets.v4.Data.Spreadsheet
$spreadsheet.Properties = New-Object Google.Apis.Sheets.v4.Data.SpreadsheetProperties
$spreadsheet.Properties.Title = "New Spreadsheet"

# Create the new spreadsheet
$spreadsheet = $service.Spreadsheets.Create($spreadsheet).Execute()

# Print the URL of the new spreadsheet
Write-Host "New spreadsheet created: $($spreadsheet.SpreadsheetUrl)"
```

Is this a reasonable direction, or another AI goof? I was reading the documentation for the NuGet provider in PowerShell and it seems like it is rather unreliable, with consistent issues installing package dependencies. Also, when I look at the documentation for the Google.Apis.Sheets.v4 library, it does not appear to provide the methods Chat-GPT says it does... could just be me though. Happy for a second opinion?

For anyone curious, the 'Google.Apis.Sheets.v4' I was looking at is here: https://googleapis.dev/dotnet/Google.Apis.Sheets.v4/latest/api/Google.Apis.Sheets.v4.SpreadsheetsResource.CreateRequest.html

Comment: I found this, it could help you get in the right direction https://jamesachambers.com/modify-google-sheets-using-powershell/

Comment: Awesome reference, thank you! Looking at the powershell module that was referenced 'UMN-Google', it does not appear to be actively maintained so I would not feel comfortable using it in production. That being said, I should be able to reference the source code and come up with a workable solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not yet sure how to upvote or reply to another existing reply, but this is what helped me recently.
I'm working on a PowerShell script that pulls a list of AD Users (filtered by either Group or OU) to a CSV file and then uploads it to a Google Sheet.
ChatGPT has helped with this as well, but the article that Bryan M referenced is definitely helpful.

> I found this, it could help you get in the right direction
> jamesachambers.com/modify-google-sheets-using-powershell –  Bryan
> Monterrosa  Apr 4, 2023 at 11:39

Answer (score -1):

It certainly had been almost 4 years and 400K downloads later, and the UMN-Google repo had no changes due to lack of need.

It has just been overhauled to be OS agnostic in pwsh 7.4, and backwards compatible to 5.1. It also leverages new functionality using the JSON auth files from the Google project instead of relying on the PFX files along with replacing dependencies on IE11 with Selenium, or no browser (interactive Device log in).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please, [edit] and try for [answer], describe the effect of what you propose and explain why it helps to solve the problem. Consider taking the [tour].